# How to change Items in gallery dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic, gallery, adapter

In my android app I have this scenario - 
I have a Gallery where I have to display some images.
I have a total of 13 images each of which I get by calling a function with some parameters.

Now in my adapter for gallery I can only pass 7 images at a time and when the user scrolls through the gallery I should update the gallery items.
eg. My images are {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}.

First time I can only get and show {3,4,5,6,7,8,9} with 6 at center-display
now if the user scrolls rightwards I want to remove 3 from the left end and add 10 at the right end so that the adapter array becomes {4,5,6,7,8,9,10} with 7 at center and so on.

Similarly if the user scrolls leftward i want to remove 9 from right end and add 2 at the left end so that the adapter array becomes {2,3,4,5,6,7,8} with 5 at the center.

I am using LinkedList for storing my items

How can I achieve this.
Please Help.

Comment: Are you using a custom gallery activity/layout you've written yourself?

Comment: Yes I have a custom gallery but the adapter in it works exactly the same way as in normal gallery code.

Comment: You'll find it easier to get answers if you try something first. And sry, I can't help.

Comment: I have already writtem some code. I am using Linked List and inside Gallery View's onItemSelected I am trying to carry out my operation for adding and removing items. I am using LinedList's removeLast and addFirst methods.

Comment: And how come it's not working? No visible changes? Remember to update the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a custom class extends Gallery, Override `onFling()` detect gesture(left or right) and do your operation of removing.

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
        // This is an horizontal fling
            if (velocityX < 0) {
                // From left to right => go forward 
                //  remove 3
                return true;
            } else if (velocityX > 0) {
                // From right to left => go backward
                //  remove 7
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        // This is a vertical fling
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for responding. Actually I want to know what operation to preform for removing and adding items. I am using Linked List to store my items (just edited). I want to carry out my operation inside gallery view's onItemSelected()